# ActionBar SearchView: overlay floating text

Tags: android, listview, android-actionbar, searchview, android-appcompat

I'm trying to use `SearchView` provided in `android.support.v7` to filter a `Listview`.

Everything seems fine, except for a "`strange floating text`" that appears in overlay over my typed text and `listview` rows (and doesn't disappear if I stop typing).

How can I disable it? What type of element is it?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: That strange floating text will not appear unless you make so. Can you show us your code?

Comment: It might be due to the `Swype` keyboard, try to reproduce it by using `Default` keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: in onQueryTextChange I was using list.setFilterText(s) instead of filtering the array